# Full Screen Custom Video Player but when I expand for full screen, controls don't appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have Created a custom video player. When mouse Cursor move to the player then the video controls panel are visible like see the snapshot.

[image]
but when I clicked on to expand button for full screen then hole video controls will disappear.

[image]

I want to add the video controls when it's full screen. Can anyone help me to fix up this issue?

Please see the Google Drive link there I have uploaded the main file. I would be grateful if anyone can solve this!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z79Mg-gkDEM41MSTZoxJkot3fjNl0KGP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it asks for permission to download. can you make it public?

Comment: sir please download it. i tried to find out the public option but there don't have any public options.

Comment: Can't you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) out of it instead ?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: sir it's now public. i have changed the options

Comment: Check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question (in text form, [properly formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)), and not just dumped onto an external site/service. Please edit your question accordingly.